# angular material mat select empty value triggers 2 times on change event

Tags: javascript, angular7, angular-material-6

I have a dropdown code and i have used angular material 6.4.1.

```
<mat-form-field floatLabel="never">
    <mat-select name="country" [formControl]="userForm['country']" 
                (selectionChange)="onCountryChange($event)">
        <mat-option [value]="null">
            None
        </mat-option>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let country of countries" [value]="country.id">
            {{country.name}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

If i select any country from the dropdown list onCountryChange() will trigger once, but if i change country value to **None** onCountryChange() is triggering 2 times.

Can any one help with this, i have tried different ways to resolve it but no luck.